# is using namespace foo inside a class acceptable?

Tags: c++, namespaces, using-directives

I know that we should not add a code like this in a header file:

```
using namespace std;
```

but what about this:

```
namespace foo
{
    class A
    {
     public:
        void add()
        {
             using namespace std;
             // do some work here 
         }
    }
}
```

As far as I know then std is only brought out into function add and no to any other classes in the name space.

Is it still not acceptable? Why?

Comment: No, and the compiler would tell you so. In any case, if `class A` is in namespace `foo`, it automatically looks up names in `foo`.

Comment: You can add it to an individual member function, but not to the entire class.

Comment: @BoPersson : is it acceptable to do so? adding to individual member functions?

Comment: Why don't you ask that question, instead of asking whether code that doesn't compile is acceptable?

Comment: @mans - I rarely do it, but it is allowed. You should also consider if typing 20 characters in the directive actually saves you anything. `std::` is just 5 characters.

Comment: @juanchopanza I changed my question in this effect!

Comment: And you didn't even try to compile it.

Comment: @juanchopanza You are right and it is my bad, sorry for it.